# Seagate Hybrid Drive 2TB

Tags: windows

Hi I have an internal Seagate SSHD 2TB drive and I want to do a clean install of windows but when I boot using the windows disk, only one partition is visible. should I not be able to see the SSD part of the Drive

Comment: ..........what? what do you mean by the `SSD part of the drive` exactly?

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't. The solid-state part is used as a cache to the mechanical hard drive, in order to speed up certain file operations. It's not meant to be used as a separate drive.

For more information, see [this article](http://www.seagate.com/tech-insights/adaptive-memory-in-sshd-master-ti) from Seagate.